# Why does it throw an internal server error (500) due to MySQL

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql-workbench

I'm facing an issue that I can't seem to fix... I wrote some PHP and JavaScript code to be able to like posts on my web application. It works **BUT** for some pictures when I try to like or dislike the picture it likes or dislikes **twice**. I don't know why it does that, but because of this I get the error: `500 (internal server error) - Duplicate entry for key 'likes.PRIMARY'`.

Here you can see my *Likes* table [![likes table][1]][1]. Both columns have `Primary Key` and `Not Null`. I'm using **MySQL Workbench**.

The **HTML structure** for the likes on every post on the page:

```
<div class="like_container">

  <?php if (in_array($newpost->observationID,array_column($likedposts,'liked_obs_id'))): ?>
     <button class="like_button" rel="<?= $newpost->observationID?>" >
        <img class="icon_like liked" id="icon_like" src="<?= base_url()?>/public/images/heart.svg" style="height: 22px">
     </button>
     <p class="like_counts" id="like_counts" style="font-size: 18px"><?=$newpost->likes?></p>
  <?php else: ?>
     <button class="like_button" rel="<?= $newpost->observationID?>" >
        <img class="icon_like" id="icon_like" src="<?= base_url()?>/public/images/heart.svg" style="height: 22px">
     </button>
     <p class="like_counts" id="like_counts" style="font-size: 18px"><?=$newpost->likes?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

The **PHP functions** to handle the Likes are as follows:

```
private $db;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
}
public function clickLike($user, $observation)
{

    $query_text = "INSERT INTO a20ux3.likes (userID, observationID)
                    VALUES (:userID:, :observation:)";

    $query_addLike = "UPDATE a20ux3.observations 
                    SET likes = likes + 1
                    WHERE observationID = :observation:";
    $this->db->query($query_addLike, ['observation' => $observation]);
    $this->db->query($query_text, ['userID' => $user, 'observation' => $observation]);
}

public function removeLike($user, $observation)
{
    $query_text = "DELETE FROM a20ux3.likes
                    WHERE userID = :userID:
                    AND observationID = :observation:";

    $query_removeLike = "UPDATE a20ux3.observations 
                    SET likes = likes - 1
                    WHERE observationID = :observation:";
    $this->db->query($query_removeLike, ['observation' => $observation]);
    $this->db->query($query_text, ['userID' => $user, 'observation' => $observation]);
}
```

And the **JavaScript** looks like this:

```
$(".like_button").click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const button = $(this);
    let num = button[0].nextElementSibling;
    const base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
    let obs_id = button.attr("rel");
    let icon = button[0].firstElementChild;

    if(icon.classList.contains('liked')){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url +"/public/LikeController/removeLike",
            data: {ObsID: obs_id},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Removed");
                icon.classList.remove("liked");
                if ((parseInt(num.innerText) - 1) < 0){
                    num.innerText = parseInt("0");
                }
                else {
                    num.innerText = parseInt(num.innerText) - 1;
                }
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.error("Unliked unsuccessful",result);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url +"/public/LikeController/likePost",
            data: {ObsID: obs_id},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Liked");
                icon.classList.add('liked');
                num.innerText = parseInt(num.innerText) + 1;
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.error("Liked unsuccessful",result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Again I want to point out that **this error only happens when I try to like some posts on the page, not all of them**. Hopefully someone can help me out. Many thanks
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHF1l.png

Comment: You could either change `insert` to `insert ignore` or run a `select` first and send back a notice if they already have liked.... or you are trying to figure out why JS sends off twice?

Comment: @user3783243 Yes I'm trying to figure out why JS sends off twice. And I don't understand why sometimes for some posts it doesn't throw the error